# Connecting to flask app that runs on my pi

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a web application with flask that runs on my pi, for example:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'

app.run()
```

Now I want to run another Python application on my windows laptop, that sends requests to the flask application on my pi via wifi. How can I do that? Everytime I try to, I get this:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002C58FFB5198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]
```

What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your laptop can reach the Raspberry Pi normally, such as through SSH, then I suspect that Flask is only listening locally.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'

app.run(host='0.0.0.0') # Notice we are allowing outside connections here
```

Comment: Thanks! I had that problem before, but didn't remember anymore :D